# Grabbing a specific JSON key with the value

Tags: python, json

I'm using the MLB API which outputs its data in JSON format. I am wanting to grab the value of the key called 'event' for each play of the game which is in the key path liveData.plays.allPlays.result. My issue is that allPlays has multiple dictionaries/keys below it (results, about, etc...).

Running this... :

```
game_id = 748561
url = "https://statsapi.mlb.com/api/v1.1/game/{0}/feed/live".format(game_id) 
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

plays = data['liveData']['plays']['allPlays']['result']
print(plays)
```

Gives me this error:

```
plays = data['liveData']['plays']['allPlays']['result']
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

But running this:

```
plays = data['liveData']['plays']['allPlays']
for play in plays:
   event_values = play['result'].values()
print (event_values)
```

Returns with multiple lines similar to this which are each play of the game:

```
dict_values(['atBat', 'Strikeout', 'strikeout', 'Vaughn Grissom strikes out swinging.', 0, 1, 3, True])
```

Now I understand the 'result' from the first run has multiple keys in it and that I need to have a for loop to go through each 'result' dictionary which I tried but I don't know how to get only the 'event' key's value while doing that for each play which in my example would be the 2nd value called 'Strikeout' (not the lowercase strikeout).

Comment: You've not shared what your json data variable actually looks like, so it'll be difficult for us to parse it for you. The code you've share should only print once

Comment: @OneCricketeer Sorry. I updated the code in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

> the 'result' from the first run has multiple keys in it

The error is telling you it's a list. Lists don't have keys; they have indicies

This would get the second element

```
plays = data['liveData']['plays']
second = plays['allPlays'][1]
print(second['result'])
```

Beyond that, values() isn't helping print useful information. Use items() to see both key and value

Comment: I'm sure I didn't explain it well because I've been confused for the past few hours but I'm needing the value for the 'event' key which is in liveData.plays.allPlays.result.event (which is the 2nd key under 'result'). I tried your code but it returns all of the keys and values under 'result' when I've just been trying to figure out how to make it return only the second key/value.

Comment: `second['result']['event']`? Objects don't have order only lists do. You cannot dot-access a list, that's what your original error is referring to, so that path isn't correct